# Regex Replace in MySql Select query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, replace

I have this SQL query:

`SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_title = 'paul_mccartney'`

But often in `page_title` the value is like '`paul_mccartney (musician)`'. And in this case I get `NULL` back. I had the idea to regex replace everything which is between `(` and `)` including the `()`:

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE REPLACE(REGEXP('/\([^\*].*\)/U'), '', page_title) = 'paul_mccartney'
```

But it doesn't work. Is my idea possible or not? And how?

Comment: mysql regexs can only match. they're basically a fancy `where`. they don't return anything other than true/false, they don't capture, etc... you can't `replace()` the results of a regex - you'd be basically doing `replace(true/false, '', page_title)`

Comment: Where does the input "paul_mcartney" come from? Is it user input?

Comment: @MarcB I don't want to replace. I just looking for a way to get the `'paul_mccartney (musician)'` input nethertheless to `'paul_mccartney'`.

Comment: like I said, you can't do it in mysql. regexes only MATCH, and `replace` doesn't accept regexes, nor can it work with what `regex()` returns, because `regex()` only returns true/false, never the actual value(s). if the `...(...)` stuff only ever appears at the end of the string, why not `... page_title LIKE 'paul_mccartney%'`?

Comment: I have added an answer that covers how to use mysql searches to do this but as others have said above you can just use: `SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_title like '%paul_mccartney%'` and it will work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is about using RegEx but have you looked into MySQL fulltext search functions?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Using the following tutorials if you have a row that is like this:

```
Id  title
1   paul_mccartney (musician)
```

Using the example SQL provided will return a result:

```
SELECT * FROM articles
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('paul_mccartney' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `LIKE` and see how that works:

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_title LIKE '%paul_mccartney%'
```